# Will I be able to install an old version when using Mysql 5.6 as database server?

Tags: 5

Drupal 5 will go through all the install process with Mysql 5.6? Can even Drupal 5 work with Mysql 5.6?

I tried but tables were not created:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_drupal5 |
+-------------------+
| cache_filter      |
| cache_menu        |
| cache_page        |
+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

And apache logs throw a bunch of PHP warnings about Tables not existing:

```
    d May 11 13:37:45.197241 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.198008 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.198664 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.199119 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.199934 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.201507 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.202236 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.202980 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.203677 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
[Wed May 11 13:37:45.204913 2016] [:error] [pid 25342] [client 192.168.255.26:52348] PHP Warning:  Table &#039;drupal5.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist\nquery: INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, seve$
$ile=default
```

And if a reload the page it says that Drupal is already installed and if a try to run update.php get a few more warnings

## Update

If i enter install.php i get this:

```
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/www/drupal5/includes/file.inc on line 646.
warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in modules/comment/comment.info on line 3 in /var/www/drupal5/includes/module.inc on line 195.
warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in modules/drupal/drupal.info on line 3 in /var/www/drupal5/includes/module.inc on line 195.
warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in modules/node/node.info on line 3 in /var/www/drupal5/includes/module.inc on line 195.
warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in modules/poll/poll.info on line 3 in /var/www/drupal5/includes/module.inc on line 195.
```

But after that it looks fine...

Tables were created

```
    mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_drupal5       |
+-------------------------+
| access                  |
| authmap                 |
| blocks                  |
| blocks_roles            |
| boxes                   |
| cache                   |
| cache_filter            |
| cache_menu              |
| cache_page              |
| comments                |
| file_revisions          |
| files                   |
| filter_formats          |
| filters                 |
| flood                   |
| history                 |
| menu                    |
| node                    |
| node_access             |
| node_comment_statistics |
| node_counter            |
| node_revisions          |
| node_type               |
| permission              |
| role                    |
| sequences               |
| sessions                |
| system                  |
| term_data               |
| term_hierarchy          |
| term_node               |
| term_relation           |
| term_synonym            |
| url_alias               |
| users                   |
| users_roles             |
| variable                |
| vocabulary              |
| vocabulary_node_types   |
| watchdog                |
+-------------------------+
40 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

and i can enter my local site

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The error messages you are showing in the _Update_ part are not caused by MySQL, but from Drupal code not compatible with the PHP you are using.

Comment: Yes i see but at first glance after installation did not create all tables so that kind of throw me off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in [Database server [requirements]](https://www.drupal.org/node/1783060/revisions/2350168/view), Drupal 5 supports MySQL 3.23.17 or higher, even if it is recommended to use MySQL 4.1. The first Drupal version to explicitly support MySQL 5 is Drupal 7, two major versions later. I doubt Drupal 5 has been updated to fully support MySQL 5, so there could be problems when using the two together, such as the one outlined in [Error 1364 upon importing database.mysql with MySQL 5.0+](https://www.drupal.org/node/43316).

More importantly, you could get more issues causes from using Drupal 5 with PHP 5 or higher versions, such us coding using deprecated functions, removed functions, or functions for which the parameters or the result changed. In fact, [PHP [requirements]](https://www.drupal.org/node/1783062/revisions/2597238/view) expressly states that Drupal 5 doesn't support PHP 5.3.

> Drupal 5 requires PHP 4.4.0 or higher. PHP 5.2 is recommended. Drupal 5.x does not support PHP 5.3.

This is about Drupal 5 core; for any third-party modules, there can be more issues. For example, some modules could not even fully support PHP 5.2, even if Drupal core recommends it.